# Did Lagrange and/or Lebesgue and/or Lucas solve Ljunggren's equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Ljunggren’s Diophantine equation is
$$X^2+1=2Y^4.$$
In 1942, he solved it using extremely difficult means; Mordell asked for a simpler proof, so people have been trying (unsuccessfully) ever since.

But in *My Numbers, My Friends*, Ribenboim says that the equation ”had been solved by Lagrange (1777) by the method of descent.” Additionally, Dickson (*History*, Vol. II) writes “A. Cunningham noted that the solution of (2) by Lebesgue and Lucas appears to be complete and to indicate that the only integral solutions of $x^2-2y^4=-1$ are $(1,1)$ and $(239,13)$”. I’ve been told by several mathematicians (including Noam Elkies, in an email of just over a week ago), that there is no elementary solution.

So…

> **QUESTION:** Was Ljunggren’s equation solved by Lagrange and/or Lebesgue and/or Lucas?

Comment: just gonna point out the L-tendency to the names

Comment: not enough for an L-series

Comment: @JacobClaassen: Kinda reminds me of the same with Superman's Lois Lane, Lana Lang, and Lex Luther. What the heck with the L's.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Speaking as a composer and music director, the L's make perfect sense for the femme(s) fatale(s), because of the liquidness and lusciousness of the sound ("L" is a voiced consonant). For Lex…? I got nothing.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: The things I learn in MSE. :)

Comment: There is a reference in [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ar7gBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=had+been+solved+by+Lagrange+(1777)+by+the+method+of+descent&source=bl&ots=QLPXOJ-aB6&sig=UPyA1cK5Oa3sJVTiBnbc6mTH1DM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7tb7795XWAhUBQ48KHUhlD34Q6AEILzAE#v=onepage&q=had%20been%20solved%20by%20Lagrange%20(1777)%20by%20the%20method%20of%20descent&f=false) regarding Lagrange's paper on "the Diophantine Equation $2x^4 - y^4 = \pm z^2$ and related problems". I currently don't have access to a laptop/pc so can't investigate further.

Comment: the solutions of equation$2Z^2=X^2+1$ makes two sets of numbers with certain recursive relations:$x=1,7,239,8119,. . .$ with recursive relation:$34 x_{i-1 }-x_{i-2}$ and $z=1, 5, 169, 5741 . . .$ with recursive relation $34 z_{i-1} -z_{i-2} $. It must be checked whether 1 and 169 are the only squares in set z to satisfy equation $2Y^4=X^2+1$ ;$z=y^2$.

Comment: I wonder, Kieran, whether you have tried tracking down the (alleged) papers of Lagrange, Cunningham, Lebesgue, Lucas to see for yourself what they did or did not prove?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I did eventually do that: they [all] proved descent mechanisms for integer solutions of $2Y^4 - X^2 = Z^2$, but did not (at least, to my mind) rigorously prove that there are no other solutions with $Z=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two remarks before I turn to the answer: Ribenboim's references are notoriously unreliable, Dickson's references are almost always accurate.

In the case at hand, Dickson's (2) is the equation $2x^4 - y^4 = z^2$. Its integral solutions correspond to rational solutions of $2X^4 - 1 = Z^2$. The determination of rational points on curves of genus $1$ (in this case) is not very hard.

Determining the integral solutions of $2X^4 - 1 = Z^2$ is difficult; I am not sure what Dickson wanted to say, but clearly he does not claim that anyone had proved that the only integral solutions of your equation are $(1,1)$ and $(239,13)$.